# Is it possible to let players pick up and use certain items in Minecraft, without breaking blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to make an escape the room style game in minecraft for my kids. Is it possible to allow players to pick up and use specific items (eg pick up a bucket, fill with water, put out fire) but not destroy any blocks (so they can’t escape the room by just breaking walls)?

Comment: Generally, the `Adventure` gamemode is for that. Only blocks explicitly allowed to be broken can be broken, possibly with proper tool etc. Adventure maps are a big 'industry' in Minecraft, professional mapmakers making good living from publishing their maps in the store. One could write a lengthy book about how to make adventure maps in MC. 'Escape rooms' are a fairly common genre among them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NBT tags](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_tags) on a tool to allow your kids to break certain blocks with that tool

Till give you a stone pickaxe that you can use to break stone and iron ore, even if you are in adventure mode, this pickaxe will also be unbreakable, which may be good in your case:

```
/give @s minecraft:stone_pickaxe{Unbreakable:1,CanDestroy:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:iron_ore"]}
```

Use this if you want the pickaxe to break as it usually would:

```
/give @s minecraft:stone_pickaxe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:iron_ore"]}
```

This will give you a bucket that you can use to pick up water:

```
/give @s minecraft:bucket{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:water"]}
```

And this will give you a water bucket, where you can place the water on stone

```
/give @s minecraft:water_bucket{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone"]}
```

Note: Some NBT-tags on a bucket will reset after using it, so I have not found a way to get a bucket that can pick up water AND place it somewhere else

I recommend to only use the first, or second command as it seems like this works inconsistently with fluids.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer by user232393, `CanDestroy` and `CanPlaceOn` can allow specific items to break or interact with specific blocks in Adventure Mode. In fact, that's the sole purpose of these NBT tags.

For a bucket that can pick up water and place it, the setup is a bit more complicated. It also assumes that you want the water to always be placible on the same blocks; that, however, would be a good idea already due to consistency alone - it will be easier for your kids to understand that e.g. prismarine = you can place water here.

#### tl.dr.: Datapacks to the rescue.

This approach also eliminates the need to prepare your map with items that have NBT tags. You can simply use items from the Creative Menu and have the datapack handle the rest.

First, you want an advancement. Name it whatever you like (I think lower snake case might be a requirement) and place it in your datapack at `data/<yournamespace>/advancements` where `<yournamespace>` is a namespace of your choice. Let's assume you use `maputils`as namespace and name your advancement `pick_up_bucket`, then the file you create needs to be `data/maputils/advancements/pick_up_bucket.json`.

You'll want an advancement that's not displayed in game, so you need a no-display parent advancement. The simplest choice is `minecraft:recipes/root`. The reward should be a command function, e.g. `handle_bucket`. As a trigger, you should use `inventory_changed` with a check for a bucket.

Here's the full JSON:

```
{
    "parent": "minecraft:recipes/root",
    "criteria": {
        "main": {
            "trigger": "minecraft:inventory_changed",
            "conditions": {
                "items": [
                    "item": "minecraft:bucket"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rewards": {
        "function": "maputils:handle_bucket"
    }
}
```

Now, for the aforementioned function. You'll first want to disable the advancement, so it can be repeated. Then, you need to take away the ordinary bucket. And finally not least, you need to hand out the modified bucket with the NBT tags. (Note: In the example below, I'm assuming you want the bucket to pick up water both from the environment and from cauldrons.)

So, the finished `data/maputils/functions/handle_bucket.mcfunction` looks like this:

```
advancement revoke @s maputils:pick_up_bucket
clear @s minecraft:bucket
give @s minecraft:bucket{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:water","minecraft:cauldron"]}
```

Now, do the same for water buckets. Remember to replace the `CanPlaceOn` tag in the function's last command with whatever blocks you want your kids to be able to place water on. If there's any more items that are supposed to function like this (such as a Beacon they're supposed to craft and place on some gold blocks, or having them break a furnace and place it on a hopper), same procedure.